# Newly Created Region is not displayed in Demonstrate block regions in Drupal-7?

Tags: drupal-7, block, regions

I have created "Above Header" Region in Drupal-7 but it is not display in Demonstrate block regions, how can i aligned created "Above Header" region.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to clear cache after adding a block to your site.

If that's not your question than would your rephrase your question please.